# Generating soapUI Rest Service Mock

Tags: rest, mocking, soapui

I created a REST service project in version 4.6.0, and added a mock.  I'm not able to add an operation for the mock.  I get..

> No unique operations to mock in project!

I am able to directly modify the onRequest script and set the response status code for GET messages.  However, when I switch to POST, which is what I really need, I get a SOAP fault string in the response:

> org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Missing/Invalid SOAP Envelope,
>   expecting [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]

How can I bypass soapUI's SOAP processing of the message? I'm trying to post a plain old XML message, not SOAP.

posting: `<test></test>`

Answer (score 1):

As Temil Sanchez writes for a [question asked on the soapUI forum](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=23569&p=54301):

> Rest Mocking was not that fully supported in 4.6.3, the only
>   workaround for Rest Mocking in 4.6.3 is located here :
>
> http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html
>
> rest mocking becomes much easier to do in our SoapUI 5.0 Release which
>   should be available on April 1st. In the meantime we have a Beta that
>   you can try here:
>
> http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=23529